# JavaScript - Node.js : (DiscordAPI) I can send title of embed in console, but get not as string

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

```
if(message.channel.id = "798844490525179915") {

    const titel = message.embeds[0].title
    console.log(titel)
    Role1 = message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === titel)
```

(starts at line 211)
line 214, gives me the right title out in console! but in line 213 I get the error, something went wrong and that my title would be "undefined" `- console puts me out the right answer (in this example "Pro Tournament.")
ERROR: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined at Client.<anonymous> (D:\Programmieren\nodeJS\EventPlaner\main.js:213:37)`

Comment: Is there definitely an embed being sent (always)? If not it would cause something like this to happen

Comment: yes, its always an embed